# What are differences between "job" and "work"?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference, synonyms

> Do you enjoy your job?

Can I use "work" instead of "job" in that sentence? Are they synonyms? How about this sentence:

> "Do you want to go for a drink after work?"

Comment: Yes in the first sentence, no in the second sentence.

Comment: Why not? Can you explain more?

Comment: If I had the time, I could. I'm sure someone else will.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To me its basically a distinction between:

> work - the physical activity itself, or the time spent working.

and

> job - the actual position, functions, duties that describe the work you do. Generally used in a broader sense than *work*.

For example:

> I *work* from 8 to 5.
>   I will be *working* at the branch office this week.

and for your examples:

> Do you enjoy your *work*?  (This is OK, referring to the actual work functions you perform.)
>   Do you want to go for a drink after *work*? (*work* refers to the time you were working that day.)

As for *job*:

> Do you enjoy your *job*? (This is OK, but more a question about your overall opinion about your position, what you do, how well you work with other, your boss, etc.)
>   Did you apply for that *job* yet?
>   It was a difficult *job* but someone had to do it.
>   I did not understand the *job* requirements.

Comment: Good answer.  One thing more to point out is that we generally say "I work at wherever" rather than "I have a job at wherever".  So, for example: "Do you have a job?"  "Yes, I work at McDonald's."

Comment: But you could also say "I got a job at McDonalds".

Comment: @user3169 - Ah, _"I got a job at McDonalds"_ – that famous refrain spoken by so many music majors shortly after graduation. :^)

Comment: @J.R. *This* music major got a job at ComputerLand.  :)

Comment: @BobRodes *My* music major trumps you all - he got a union job in a supermarket!